# Function Failed to load resource: Mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, sitefinity

i try to call a method in my sitefinity project using mvc models,
but the program tell Failed to load resource: 404, 
and never find the controller and i dont know how to resolved,
this is my code

Jquery call:

```
function myFunction(postId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/CombosController/GetCantones',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:"applicaiton/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { idprovincia: postId },
        success: function(data) {alert("success");},
        error: function() {alert("error");}
    })
}
```

Action of controller:

```
[WebMethod]
public static ActionResult GetCantones(int idprovincia)
{
     CombosBL.Provincias.JsonListados metodos = new JsonLIstados();
     List<ClaseCantones.NCanton> ListaPropiedades = metodos.GetCantonesByIdProvincia(idprovincia);
     var lista = ListaPropiedades;
     return new JsonResult { Data = lista, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code as against images

Answer (score 0):

you can call your MVC action in two ways

**First way**

- Create MVC widget. They have good article how to do that: http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-create-mvc-based-sitefinity-widgets
- Create action "GetCantones" inside your MVC widget controller
- Drop this widget to page and then call http://yourhost/pathtoyourpage/GetCantones

Example of MVC widget:

```
[ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "CombosWidget", Title = "CombosWidget", SectionName = "MVC Custom Widgets")]
public class CombosController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetCantones(int idprovincia)
    {
        //your logic is here
    }
}
```

**Second way**

Creating custom URL route to the action of your controller

Example how to do that for your case. Global.asax.cs code:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Bootstrapper.Initialized += new EventHandler<Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs>(Bootstrapper_Initialized);
    }

    protected void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CantonesApi",
            url: "api/getcantones",
            defaults: new { controller = "CombosController", action="GetCantones" }
        );
    }
```

And after that, you can call  http://yourhost/api/getcantones.